# c++ inheritance abstract function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I have a somewhat basic question on inheritance that i can seem to figure out, I've done a search and not found what I was looking for so I thought I'd ask here (not sure if title of what I'm looking for is correct).

To keep things simple I've made a bit of example code to illustrate what I'm not getting.

Basically if I have a parent `class A` and two child classes `B` & `C`,
where `A` contains common stuff (say an `id` with get/set),
while `B` & `C` have functions that are class specific.
If you declare a class `B` like: `A *bObject = new B();
how do you then access the class specific function`bObj->specific()`?

I've tried `virtual` but that requires both `B` & `C` to have the same function name / prototype declared.
I've also tried declaring the abstract in `A`, but that requires it to be prototype to be in `A`.

Where am i going wrong here? any help on this, probably basic issue would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// A class dec
class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    ~A(void);
    char id;
    void setId(char id);
    char getId();
};

// B class dec - child of A
class B :
    public A
{
public:
    B(void);
    ~B(void);
    void sayHello();
};

//C class dec - child of A
class C :
    public A
{
public:
    C(void);
    ~C(void);
    void sayGoodby();
};

//a stuff
A::A(void)
{
}
A::~A(void)
{
}
void A::setId(char id)
{
    this->id = id;
}
char A::getId()
{
    return this->id;
}

//b stuff
B::B(void)
{
    this->setId('b');
}
B::~B(void)
{
}

// c stuff
C::C(void)
{
    this->setId('c');
}
C::~C(void)
{
}
void C::sayGoodby()
{
    std::cout << "Im Only In C" << std::endl;
}
// main
void main ()
{
    A *bobj = new B();
    A* cobj = new C();

    std::cout << "im class: " << bobj->getId() << endl;
    bobj->sayHello(); // A has no member sayHello
    std::cout << "im class: " << cobj->getId() << endl;
    cobj->sayGoodby(); // A has no member sayGoodby
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access methods unique to a derived class, you need to cast the base class pointer to the correct derived class type first (a downcast):

```
A *bobj = new B();
bobj->sayHello(); // compile error
dynamic_cast<B*>(bobj)->sayHello(); // works
dynamic_cast<C*>(bobj)->sayGoodbye(); // run-time error - probably crashes with a segfault/access violation.
```

`dynamic_cast` ensures run-time type safety but adds a small overhead to the cast; for pointer casts, it returns a null pointer if the pointed-to object is not actually a B, and you should check the return value before using it. Alternatively, if you are really sure that the pointer you are casting is pointing to the correct object, you can use `static_cast` which saves you the cost of the run-time checking, but if the pointer is not pointing to the right object, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you mean `cobj` in the second case ? I don't see any undefined behavior in such case.

Comment: The second case was to illustrate what happens when you got a type mismatch (i.e., you get a null pointer and a crash if you didn't check the return value). The undefined behavior is from `static_cast`-ing a A* that's pointing to a B to a C* and trying to invoke a method on that.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, I can see how casting would work. I just tried to compile both dynamic and static casting but both returned errors, dynamic told me 

"'dynamic_cast' : 'A' is not a polymorphic type" 

and static gave me "unresolved external symbol 

@public::void__thiscall B::sayHello(void)" (errors typed out not copied) 
Is this just me being silly missing something, or is the example dynamic_cast<B*>(bobj)->sayHello(); un compellable 
Regards.

Comment: dynamic_cast requires at least one virtual method in the base class to work - my fault for not mentioning that. If you make the A destructor virtual - so `virtual ~A();`, it should work. As to the other one, the problem might be that you never implemented B::sayHello() :)

Comment: didn't see your post before this:

"-edit the second error is just me (oops)"

thanks for the reply, its helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
A *bobj = new B();
A* cobj = new C();
```

Here instance of B and C is pointed by pointer of A. Since A have no virtual function for B and C's member function sayHello() and sayGoodbye(), they could not called by `bobj->sayHello()` and `cobj->sayGoodbye()`. It is not what polymorphism should be do.

Class A should be:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    ~A(void);
    char id;
    void setId(char id);
    char getId();

    virtual void sayHello(){/* to do */ };
    virtual void sayGoodbye(){ /* to do */ };
};
```

Then the `bobj->sayHello();` and `cobj->sayGoodbye();` could be called without complaning.

Comment: but, like i explained in another reply above, this would require sayHello() and sayGoodby() in both B & C to work.?

Comment: @user2763079 Yes. By `A *bobj = new B(); bobj->sayHello();`, the `B::sayHello` is what it meant to call.

Answer (score 0):

```
A *bobj = new B();
```

The static type of `bobj` is `A *`. So, at compile time, the compiler looks for the member functions in the class `A` definition, what ever you tried to access through `bobj`. Now,

```
bobj->sayHello();
```

the compiler will look for the `sayHello` in class `A` since the type of `bobj` is `A *`. Compiler doesn't care to look into the class `B` definition to resolve the call. Since the compiler didn't find it `sayHello` member in `A`, it is complaining.

However, the dynamic type of `bobj` is `B *` and that is a where call is dispatched depending on the dynamic type.

To resolve the issue, you need to `virtual` functions of the same in class `A`.

Comment: for a common function this is great, however the problem with this is it requires the same name in all classes and that function to be common, however in this case im after a abstract function in a child class that is not common in the other child classes of A.

thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a down cast via `dynamic_cast<>`. You can implement a template method in your base class `A` to facilitate the down cast:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    virtual ~A(void);
    char id;
    void setId(char id);
    char getId();

    template <typename CHILD, typename R, typename... ARGS>
    R invoke (R (CHILD::*m)(ARGS...), ARGS... args) {
        CHILD *child = dynamic_cast<CHILD *>(this);
        if (child) return (child->*m)(args...);
        std::cout << "down cast error: " << typeid(CHILD).name() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If that particular instance of `A` was not the base of `CHILD`, then `dynamic_cast<CHILD *>(this)` result in `NULL`.  Note that the virtual destructor in `A` is required for the `dynamic_cast<>` to work.

So, you can use it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> bobj(new B());
std::unique_ptr<A> cobj(new C());

bobj->invoke(&B::sayHello);
bobj->invoke(&C::sayGoodbye);
cobj->invoke(&B::sayHello);
cobj->invoke(&C::sayGoodbye);
```

Only the first and last invocations are valid. The middle two will cause the `"down cast error"` message to be printed.

Comment: Thanks for this! this template will save casting every time, ill copy this one to the clipBoard! :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Please note that the dynamic cast won't work without the virtual destructor in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to call a function like this, you can do like this:

```
A* bobj = new B();
((B*)bobj)->sayHello();//this can be dangerous if bobj is not an instance of class B
```

however, the problem here is you do the design wrongly.
basically, if you create an class A, and subclass it to B and C. 
And then assign A* bobj = new B(); you are splitting the interfaces and implementations. That means you will use bobj as if it is an instance of class A. and you will not call the functions in B or C. B & C are implementations of interface class A.

it's just like you hire someone to build your house. You give them your blueprint(interfaces) and hire them to build. you can alter the blueprint as you like, they will do whatever in blueprint. but you can't order them directly(just like you can't call the sayHello() directly from bobj).

Comment: i totally see whats wrong here, its like im accessing from the bottom up instead of top down e.g. B* trueB = new B(); true B->everythingWorks();

Thanks for pointing that out! i may well be able to implement it the right way around with not to much work